# Dismissing ViewControllers to return to previous ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

My storyboard setup is very easy. I have two views, and the left one is the default one, sometimes the application shall switch to the second view.

I don't get it to switch back without instantiating a new root ViewController. apparently every time I "dismiss" the second view controller, a new root ViewController is created, instead of using the one that existed before. I do not use NavigationControllers, I just want to switch between two views.

What I use to present the second view

```
let infoView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "infoboard") as! InfoBoardViewController
self.present(infoView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

What I  use to dismiss it

```
UIApplication.topViewController()?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Just from second view controller call `dismiss(animated: false, completion: 
nil)`

Comment: Thanks, Robert, that helped me dismiss the ViewController successfully. Now still, the problem is when returning to the root ViewController it gets opened another time (twice now). So I think when I dismiss the second view controller I need to dismiss the first one as well? Every time I dismiss the ViewController2 a new ViewController is being added additionally to the previous ones.

Comment: @MaxF Your scenario does not sound like normal behavior. How do you know it is creating a new root?

Comment: I have a listener for applicationDidBecomeActive to refresh the data on it. I also print that to the log and recognize that it refreshes the data twice when dismissing the second view, or three times when dismissing it again.

Comment: I've got it fixed. The multiple runs were due to adding an observer every time the view became active resulting in multiple observers getting called. Now when the first view disappears the observer gets removed. Thanks y'all.